# code working fine, just problem is on successful operation, successful message not working

Tags: python, django

This code is working Fine Updating User password the only problem am facing that on successful operation. Success msg is not printing on page

views.py

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('change_password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

change_password.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<!-- {{messages}} -->

{{ pwd_updated }}
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

i tried this but this is also not working:

```
        print(messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!'))
```

also tried this:

```
    pwd_updated = messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
    return redirect('change_password',{'pwd_updated':pwd_updated})
```

& fetching it on my html.

but not working.

Comment: What is message?

Comment: `messages` is a list, have you tried cycling through it?

Comment: @AmitNanaware this line: messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!'))

Comment: So what is messages? is it list or any other object?

Comment: @AmitNanaware Read the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In change_password.html try to use this below code:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}

    ...

{% endblock %}
```

That should help.